# About the Windows BYTE and PBYTES data types

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, byte

What is "BYTE" and "PBYTE" used for?.I couldn't find any information on the internet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

BYTE by='a';
PBYTE pby= &by;

int main(){
  
  cout<<"by  :  "<<by<<endl;
  cout<<"&by :  "<<&by<<endl; // Why doesn't it return the memory address?
  cout<<"pby :  "<<pby<<endl;
  cout<<"&pby:  "<<&pby;
  
  return 0;
}

The console shows:

by  :  a
&by :  a
pby :  a
&pby:  00007FF6CC10A008
```

I just want to know what BYTE and PBYTE are used for. I can not understand. Thanks

Comment: Until someone finds a duplicate: `BYTE` is a type alias for `unsigned char` (see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)). The type of `&by` is `unsigned char*`. There is an overloaded `<<` operator which takes any type of pointer to `char` (`char*`, `signed char*` and `unsigned char*`) and treats it as a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string. Since `&by` isn't such a pointer, you actually have *undefined behavior*. You need to cast the pointer to a `void*` to get the address. You have the same problem with `pby`.

Comment: If you're using *any* visual studio environment (community, pro, enterprise, code, whatever), just highlight the prospect in-code and hit F12 and follow the bread-crumbs. The odd output you're seeing is due to specific overloads of `operator <<` against the types under `BYTE` and `PBYTE`, which I'd lay heavy money is `unsigned char` and `unsigned char*` respectively.

Comment: You said *I cannot find any information on the internet*, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) for some information. You should not use `BYTE` unless you are doing Windows programming, and even then I would not recommend it, if you want a byte data type use `uint8_t` which is standard C++, not WIndows specific.

Comment: [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) Remember that lots of the WinAPI date back to the 16 bit era and also MS-Windows supports non-Intel architecture. So some data abstractions are 30 years old, remain for backwards compatibility, and might not be relevant today or on your architecture.

Comment: Forget the `PBYTE` type. Don't use it but use `BYTE *` instead, itr's the same thing. And if you see `PBYTE` is existing code or in MS documentation, think of it as `BYTE*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BYTE,PBYTE is very old style in windows programming. If you want to allocate heap memory for your image loader for example, you can write

```
    unsigned char* img = new unsigned char[1024 * 1024];
    load_image(img, ....);
    conv_image(img, ....);
```

But your finger would be tired, so you can write

```
    PBYTE img = new BYTE[1024 * 1024];
```

Yes, microsoft invented these defined types over 20yr ago.
But it is not portable and not follows standards and cause memory leaks, so in the 21st century, you should write as described below.

```
    auto img = make_shared<uint8_t>(1024 * 1024);
or
    vector<uint8_t> v(1024 * 1024);
or
    array<uint8_t, 1024 * 1024>  a;   // need enough stack memory
```

Comment: Using vector instead of new has nothing to do with using BYTE against uint8_t.

Answer (score 1):

> What is "BYTE" and "PBYTE" used for?.I couldn't find any information on the internet.

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

```
BYTE    A byte (8 bits).
This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

```
PBYTE   
A pointer to a BYTE.
This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
typedef BYTE *PBYTE;
```

There's also [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), which documents:

> std::byte is a distinct type that implements the concept of byte as specified in the C++ language definition.
> Like char and unsigned char, it can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects (object representation), but unlike those types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. A byte is only a collection of bits, and only bitwise operators are defined for it.

Answer (score -1):

> What is "BYTE" and "PBYTE" used for?

`BYTE` is a type alias for `unsigned char` and `PBYTE` is a type alias for `BYTE *`, a.k.a. `unsigned char *`. They are used in the WINAPI as same their "real" type - `unsigned char` and a pointer to a `unsigned char`

In your code:

```
cout << "&by : ";
cout << "&phy : ";
```

will take the pointer of that string literal in memory, and print out all the the characters that follows until it reached a `\0` (that how null-terminated string works). Then, it returns a `basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&`, allowing you to chain multiple calls.

When you call `cout << &by`, you are calling the overloaded operator for `basic_ostream << const unsigned char *__s`. If you dig a little deeper in the code,

```
template<typename _Traits> inline basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&
    operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& ___out, const unsigned char* __s)
{
    return (___out << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(__s));
}
```

You will find that what is does is simply casting that `const unsigned char*` to a `const char*` (Notice how the `unsigned char*` is a `const` because it is a global variable). In another word, it works exactly same as `cout << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&by)`, where the program treat your `&by` as a null-terminated string. Since the allocated on the stack is reset to `\0`s, the `by` is same as a one-character long null-terminated string (`"a\0"`).

On the another hand, when you call `cout << &pby`, you are calling the overloaded operator for `__ostream_type& << const void*`. The program is casting the `PBYTE *` to a void pointer as there isn't an overload for `PBYTE *` (`BYTE **`). In this case, it simply print out the address of `pby`.

```
__ostream_type& operator<<(const void* __p) {
     return _M_insert(__p);
}
```

Comment: This question is not about how `<<` works. This question is succintly stated in its first sentence. You apparently misread the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I disagree. The OP wrote `// Why doesn't it return the memory address?` along with the console output in his code. `PBYTE` and `BYTE` is declared in `windows.h` and it is obvious enough that they are used within the WINAPI. The question "I just want to know what BYTE and PBYTE are used for" apparently comes from **how `cout << &by` is not printing the address of `by`**.

Comment: I am wanting to learn how to use Winapi. I am researching about the data types used by this API. So I'm doing tests. Small programs that show me the value of the variables in the console. That's why I referenced what the console was showing. But my real question is: What are these data types used for?

Comment: There's two question - one for their usage and one for "how the cout call doesn't print out the memory". `BYTE` is a type alias for `unsigned char` and `PBYTE` is a type alias for `BYTE *`, a.k.a. `unsigned char *`. Does that answer your question?